# Error Installing cf command by gem in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, cloud-foundry

I want to push my project to cloud foundry, but when i tried to install cf command for cloud foundry CLI, that was came an error :

```
   user@computer:~$ sudo gem install cf
   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
   ERROR:  Error installing cf:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

           /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
   /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file --mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'


  Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
  Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

i used ubuntu 13.10, and gem 1.8.23.
Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to install another package to get this working, specifically the Ruby 1.9-dev package:

`sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev`

If that doesn't work, try:

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new client, written in Go. You can download it from the Github page https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli

It's way quicker than the Ruby client, as it's native.